# UIDatePicker Output

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have attached the UITextField to the UIDatePicker for month, day, year only. When I select the date the text output in the UITextField displays the date and time still. How do i get the UItextfield to display only the month, day, and year? Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
    [datePicker setDate:[NSDate date]];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [self.dateField setInputView:datePicker];



    [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTextField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

}



-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.dateField.inputView;

    self.dateField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",picker.date];
}
```

Comment: You have to move past coding to debugging. There is the Xcode debugger and `NSLog` for `caveman` displaying variables, etc. Find if the `updateTextField:` method is being called. Separate the `self.dateField.inputView` statement into it's components, get the date text and NSLog it. Do less in each statement, break them up into more statement, each one doing one thing (the compiler will merge them together). Then you will see the problem. SO is **not** your debugger, it is a "last resort".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

```
-(void)updateTextField:(id)sender
{
    UIDatePicker *picker = (UIDatePicker*)self.dateField.inputView;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM dd yyyy"];
    self.dateField.text =  [dateFormat stringFromDate:picker.date];

 }
```